# How to apply scss with Module federation in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I am working on a module-federation prototype with webpack5 and the Angular 11 using below package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-architects/module-federation

There is a know issue with this package while using styles.

> Bug with styleUrls Currently, there is, unfortunately, a bug in the
> experimental CLI/webpack5 integration causing issues when using shared
> libraries together with components pointing to styleUrls. For the time
> being, you can work around this issue by removing all styleUrls in
> your applications and libraries.

So, the solution is to put all css's in HTML with  tag.

In my case I have existing project which uses SCSS. If I want to use micro front-end using this given package, I have to migrate my all SCSS in CSS and put it in HTML file which is very big task.

Question: Is there any better way to handle SCSS with the project having micro front-end which uses package @angular-architects/module-federation?

Comment: Update - With Angular 14 and latest version of webpack module federation package. SCSS are supported now